# Getting Error: Request failed with status code 404 at createError (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15) on a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, slack-api

I am trying to reproduce something very similar to this https://github.com/leighhalliday/slack-app-demo

The only differences are the .env conf files and the web hook links, and I am using express-promise-router instead of express.Router() because the code at the above Github project will throw unresolved promise errors. A suggestion was to use the express-promise-router, which helped with the unresolved promises but created another issue.

If I go to http://localhost:3000/alert I get this in the terminal:

GET /alert 500 2055.126 ms - 759
Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
at settle (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:244:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

My folder looks like this:

[image: File Folders]

The relevant code looks like this, App.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
var router = require('express-promise-router')();

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var alertRouter = require("./routes/alert");

var app = express();

app.use(router);
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/alert", alertRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

Index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = require('express-promise-router')();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And Alert.js, I strongly suspect the issue is here somewhere:

```
const Axios = require("axios");
var express = require("express");
var router = require('express-promise-router')();

router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  const symbol = "SHOP";
  const result = await Axios.get(
    `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${symbol}&apikey=${process.env.API_KEY}`
  );
 
  const lastRefreshed = result.data["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"];
  const lastClose =
    result.data["Time Series (Daily)"][lastRefreshed]["4. close"];

    console.log(lastClose);

  await Axios.post(
    `https://hooks.slack.com/services/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`,
    {
      blocks: [
        {
          type: "section",
          text: {
            type: "mrkdwn",
            text: `Alert! Alert! *${symbol}* is now $${lastClose}. <https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE:+${symbol}|View on Google Finance>`,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  res.json({
    lastClose,
    date: new Date().toISOString(),
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

So, what I going wrong here? Would it make sense to use the code as in the very first link to the original Github project and handle the unresolved promises(and how) or is it better to carry on with express-promise-router?

I am not sure I have initialized and/or exported express-promise-router properly. Thanks for any resolutions and suggestions.

Comment: In axios anything other than 200 is treated as an error. Check first Axios request may be an error is originated from there.

Comment: @Vibhas how would I check that? I am not familiar with debugging dependencies, any help would be great